# Comment transposer le « mockbuster » ?

Tags: traduction, vocabulaire, anglais, anglicismes, cinéma

On a l'anglicisme [*mockbuster*](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mockbuster), par analogie avec le *blockbuster* (grand titre, super-production) que [Wiktionnaire](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/mockbuster) définit comme étant une « réalisation plus ou moins plagiée sur une œuvre à gros budget, à connotation humoristique ». Comprendre le terme sans explication implique de comprendre l'analogie qui implique de comprendre le terme anglais *blockbuster* attesté en 1952 en anglais, et dont le sens antérieur attesté une décénie auparavant est le dommage à grande échelle causé par une bombe ([Etymonline](https://www.etymonline.com/search?q=blockbuster)).

A-t-on des suggestions, soit un mot-valise, soit un adjectif significatif en épithète à un nom, soit simplement un terme courant qu'on peut recycler aisément ou autrement ? On trouve parfois que l'anglicisme est bien adapté ; je ne suis pas de cet avis.

Comment: Même blockbuster n'a pas de transposition, non? Pour des mots aussi spécifiques, personnellement je trouve qu'un anglicisme est plus adapté. Sinon on peut utiliser imitation, calque, plagiat, inspiration, influence, etc.

Comment: J'ai simplement donné mon avis dans les commentaires, je n'ai pas répondu à la question. Tu l'as expliqué toi-même dans ta question, il y a beaucoup d'implications à comprendre derrière le terme. C'est une expression qui a une référence historique dans un contexte anglais. Les exemples que tu as donnés ont tous des équivalents en anglais (ex: great success, big title), mais perdent la valeur de l'expression. C'est pourquoi, **personnellement**, je trouve que l'anglicisme est plus adapté. :)

Comment: Défit intéressant. Le terme est peu usité en France et quad la presse l'emploi ils se sentent obligé de l'expliquer. J'ai plussoyé ta réponse aussi mais je pense qu'on pourrait aussi chercher quelque chose du côté de parasite/taire  parce qu'il y a aussi dans le concept : « production parfaitement opportuniste qui cherche à profiter des flux médiatiques fabriqués pour les besoins d'une grosse machine afin d'y faire voler ses propres minables embarcations ». Bien définit [par cet article](https://www.liberation.fr/cinema/2012/02/15/un-petit-coin-de-parodie_796095/).

Comment: Pour ma part, je connaissais pas la dimension humoristique ou parodique. D'ailleurs je note qu'elle n'est pas mentionné sur la page wikipedia (https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mockbuster).

Comment: @Simon En France tout le monde ne comprend pas le terme de *blockbuster*, le mot reste confiné au domaine des critiques et amateurs du 7e art.  FranceTerme recommande l'emploi de  « Production à gros budget ». Monsieur tout le monde parlera éventuellement de film à gros succès. L'anglicisme n'est pas toujours adapté si on veut être compris de tous. FranceTerme ne donne pas encore d'équivalent pour *mockbuster*, mais parce que le mot n'est pratiquement pas employé en France, ça viendra... la question est donc utile.

Comment: Suite... Je vois qu'au Québec pour *blockbuster* c'est [superproduction](http://gdt.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=26540859) qui est proposé. Ils ne connaissent pas encore *mockbuster*... trop récent probablement...

Comment: @None Merci, j'avais pas vu que l'article de _Libération_ parle de The Asylum et a _parodie_ dans le titre. Pour le choix dans le GDT pour _blockbuster_, je suis critique de choix vu la note _La superproduction est souvent un film à grand succès_. Et donc pas toujours. Je pense que le sens du truc qui _bust_ un _block_, c'est l'impact, l'effet, pas ce qui propulse ou la grosseur de la production. Je trouve donc _film à grand succès_ bien meilleur. Je pense qu'en France par exemple si on regarde les films genre The Asylum on a déjà tout le vocab. pour parler de ça, dont parodie etc.

Answer (score 1):

Je pense que je vais simplement dire qu'il s'agit d'une « parodie dérivée d'un film à grand succès (genre cinématographique) », comme les sens de la [*parodie*](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/parodie) permettent je crois de jumeler l'idée de l'*imitation* et celle de l'*humour* ; je préfère parler du succès du film plutôt que de la taille de la production ou de la « [machine](http://www.culture.fr/franceterme/result?francetermeSearchTerme=grosse%20machine&francetermeSearchDomaine=0&francetermeSearchSubmit=rechercher&action=search) » parce qu'on n'aurait pas imité un *grosse machine* qui n'a connu aucun succès commercial.

Sinon c'est un défi de formuler un mot, et j'ai pensé à des trucs comme *calque-succès* ou *croque-succès*, voir *moque-succès* (le [*mock*](https://learnersdictionary.com/definition/mock) de *mockbuster* c'est l'*imitation*, pas la moquerie, mais sa morphologie, sa prononciation et l'idée de *parodie*, que je crois juste, autoriserait il me semble l'amalgame). Ça vaut ce que ça vaut.